# Fill in gaps in cumulative query

Tags: oracle

I have the following query to calculate a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT to_char(INVC_DT, 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTH,
       SUM(INVC_AMT),
       SUM(SUM(INVC_AMT)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(INVC_DT))
FROM T_INVC_INFO I INNER JOIN T_TASK_INFO T ON I.TASK_ID = T.TASK_ID
WHERE T.CNTRCT_ID = #session.user.cntrct_id#
GROUP BY to_char(INVC_DT, 'MON-YYYY')
ORDER BY MONTH DESC;
```

The problem I have is that I need to fill in the gaps in time.  For example, if I have data for JAN, FEB, and APR, I need another row for MAR with value 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may introduce a calendar table into your query, which will represent every month/year which you want to appear in your output.  Assuming you wanted to cover all of 2017 to 2019, you might try:

```
WITH years AS (
    SELECT '2017' AS year FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019' FROM dual
),
months AS (
    SELECT 'JAN' AS month FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'FEB' FROM dual UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'DEC' FROM dual
)

SELECT
    m.month || '-' || y.year AS MONTH,
    SUM(INVC_AMT),
    SUM(SUM(INVC_AMT)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(INVC_DT))
FROM years y
CROSS JOIN months m
LEFT JOIN T_INVC_INFO i
    ON m.month || '-' || y.year = TO_CHAR(i.INVC_DT, 'MON-YYYY')
LEFT JOIN T_TASK_INFO t
    ON i.TASK_ID = t.TASK_ID AND
       t.CNTRCT_ID = #session.user.cntrct_id#
WHERE
    TO_DATE(m.month || '-' || y.year, 'MON-YYYY') BETWEEN
        (SELECT MIN(INVC_DT) FROM T_INVC_INFO) AND
        (SELECT MAX(INVC_DT) FROM T_INVC_INFO)
GROUP BY
    m.month || '-' || y.year
ORDER BY
    MONTH DESC;
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it dynamic, by either passing in parameters or even better by calculating the min and max values present in the table?

Comment: @alanfcm I updated my question which partially meets your requirements.  Now the `WHERE` clause of the query restricts the dates coming from the calendar table to only between the min and max invoice dates.  Beyond this, you might need to use dynamic SQL (e.g. a stored procedure).

Comment: Well by your own request my answer now only spans the range of invoice dates.  Do these empty months lie outside of this range?

Comment: No, they are inside.

Comment: Try the updated answer.  I moved the restriction on the contract ID to the `ON` clause of the join.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202820/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-tim-biegeleisen).